# How can I control what topics are shown in the topics bar under the search bar?

Tags: youtube

[image: Topics bar]

Specifically I am interested in having certain topics always shown. For example, Youtube will often offer me the Mathematics topic, but not always. I want Mathematics, always!

Comment: Here is a link that explains what little customization you can do.  [Manage your recommendations & search results](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6342839?hl) navigate to the section **Tune your recommendations > Computer > Choose topics in your recommendations**